# Is there no appropriate form to this question?

Tags: discussion

This is a question of mine, soon to be closed: [Given Concepts, are SFINAE helpers intended to be kept as non-deprecated? [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057545/given-concepts-are-sfinae-helpers-intended-to-be-kept-as-non-deprecated).

As a C++ programmer I need to know what language features are at my disposal. When writing new code or maintaining existing code I obviously make decision by planning ahead according to, for example, which features are planned to be deprecated.

The way I see the case, and please teach me otherwise if I get it wrong here, as I'm rather new as an active member, is as follows:

1. I don't see how whether something is announced or not is a matter of
   opinion. It was caused by someone's (on the committee) opinion, but
   so was many other things that are now fact, which are the subject of
   many legitimate questions on the site -- for good reason.
2. It is not a matter of asking for external resource more than asking
   for knowledge, one I wasn't able to find on-line, but that now I
   have found thanks to this very question.
3. Effectively speaking, it is not a temporarily relevant question in 
   terms of it being at least relevant for the way I'm about to make 
   coding related decisions in the next couple of years at least.

Again, I'd love any reasoned articulation either in support or claiming otherwise.

Comment: Usually the "recommendation question" close reason is for tutorial or library. Applying it to a proposal is rather unusual. I'm not sure.

Comment: "*When writing new code or maintaining existing code I obviously make decision by planning ahead according to, for example, which features are planned to be deprecated.*" That's what deprecation *is for*. Deprecated does not mean "removed" or "never use". It means "eventually to be removed." It's still valid and legal, and it's OK to use a feature that has not yet been deprecated, even if you believe that it will become deprecated in 2 years, since even if it is, it won't be *removed* for another 6 or more.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, so far so good. Sounds like you do agree, to a certain extent, that it is a point for consideration in the context of coding. Would you then leave the question open in its current form?

Comment: The things that can actually be answered here are: features formally listed among future language extensions, features part of working draft and features part of defect reports (DR). Everything else is just speculation. The internal works of the ISO WG are not necessarily public, and if they are, they would probably be posted at the official site: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/

Comment: @Lundin I just saw [this really great answer of yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251795/2754173), which, even as a newcomer, I can totally relate to. Do you feel this question of mine regarding language features is contributing to this negative trend in any of the ways you have described? I'm seriously asking and I'd like to know only so I could improve as an asker as well.

Comment: @Lundin For one, I tried to find such a resource for DRs or proposals and didn't manage to, prior to asking. And I'm sure you will agree that knowing of such a resource and how to reach it is a prerequisite for knowing not to ask this question. Regardless of knowing what's appropriate to be asked on the site. I really hate paying the price of the closed question of mine for not knowing about the existence of said off-site resource.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist: "*Sounds like you do agree, to a certain extent, that it is a point for consideration in the context of coding.*" No, that is in fact the *opposite* of what I said. What does it matter whether something *might* get *deprecated*? Use what is available now and let the future work itself out. If it ever does gets deprecated, there will be plenty of time to transition to concepts directly (assuming you don't want to do that immediately once C++20 becomes viable).

Comment: @NicolBolas OK friend, I'm letting this one go for now. I think I might have misinterpreted some of your replies, but it's OK, I guess some of it is pretty subtle in regards to the phrasing. Thanks for all your time and knowledge sharing.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist First of all, the post is from 2014 :) Sadly though, it is just as relevant today, since the situation has only gotten worse since then. But I think you can relax; your original question before edits is rather vague, but not down in the gutter like some of those examples I made in that old post.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515162/snprintf-are-there-any-c-standard-proposals-plans-to-change-the-description-of) is a very similar question to yours (for C) and I think it's fine - the poster managed to narrow it down enough to suit the SO format, even though it's not a specific coding problem as such, but rather a programmer problem. I would recommend using [tag:language-lawyer] when it comes to questions about details of the C++ standard.

Comment: @Lundin Ok glad to hear. Sad about the situation on SO though. About the original question I'd attribute the rather too vague of a phrasing to my too short time as an active member -- I did post it as part of an immediate attempt to rectify it in accordance with the inputs from the community. Hopefully it can be looked at not as a destructive usage of the site, but rather as a means to learn how to be a positive contributor. Oh and I did tag it [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) from the get go! : )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So there's three questions in your post. The first:

> My question is whether such a proposal for deprecation has been submitted...

is probably fine. There's three possible answers for this:

- Yes
- No
- There's no official means of finding out

Each of which would be an objective statement of fact. Your second question,

> ...or if a committee member has declared the intent to make such a proposal?

is impossible to answer in the negative. Unless "declaring intent" is referring to a formal process, there's no way to be sure that no one has never said that they might do this. At best someone would be guessing that no committee member has ever said this.

Your third question,

> Alternatively, I'd like to know if there's a place where a non committee member such as myself can see the currently submitted proposals.

is a find request, which is off topic.

Comment: OK roger that. 1. So if I'll remove the second and third questions you say it's fine for the site? 2. What about changing the 3rd question to "Is there are way to see C++ language committee proposals such that I can plan better when writing code?"

Comment: BTW just took what I interpreted as you advice and left only the first question.

Comment: 1. I say "probably". You aren't directly asking where to find proposals in that question, you're asking whether a specific one exists. One could argue that it's close enough. 2. If the first question is OK you shouldn't need to ask the third since an answer would either include a link to the proposals or tell you there isn't a place to find out.

Comment: OK appreciate it. Figured so too after reading your answer one more time. Hence went and made the change